# How to Remove "Prepare for submission" App from iTunesConnect Dashboard

Tags: app-store-connect

I create an app for testing purpose but now I am not able to remove it from the iTunesConnect Dashboard? How can I remove it?

There is no "Delete" option under the "App Information" tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can only delete app if you have atleast 1 approved version of app. Refer this link for instructions on deleting app from iTunescnnect https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: So there is no way to remove it from my dashboard?

Comment: not unless you get your app approved once. If app was never made live, let it be there.. there is no harm? Is there specific reason you want to get it out of your dev account?

Comment: No particular reason I just want to remove it since I do not need it. Anyway, thanks @AmodGokhale for all these info.